# Getting the error of NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! in angular testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, e2e-testing, angular-test

While running the ng test in angular I am getting the error as
SidebarComponent > should create
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AuthserviceService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!

**sidebar.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar.component';

describe('SidebarComponent', () => {
  let component: SidebarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SidebarComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SidebarComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SidebarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NgModule ,Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ChartsModule, ThemeService } from 'ng2-charts';
import { AuthserviceService } from './authservice.service';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './shared/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/footer/footer.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './main/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './shared/spinner/spinner.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './main/about/about.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from './main/notifications/notifications.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { UserinfoComponent } from './userinfo/userinfo.component';
import { ReportComponent } from './main/report/report.component';
import { Shared } from './shared.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    SpinnerComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    MainComponent,
    UserinfoComponent,
    ReportComponent,
 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ChartsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    ],
  providers: [ThemeService,AuthserviceService,DashboardService,Shared],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am new to this testing can anyone help me for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup the test with all the imports and providers you require. When you launch the test suite with ng test each spec is isolated and the AppModule is not used, so you have to setup everything again the test case.

In this particular case you should add the HttpClientTestingModule to the import array in the test case, just below the declarations array. After that you may encounter other errors, you will have to keep adding modules and providers until it works, the error messages will help to find the errors.

This link may help: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios